# Drop-down-menu looks strange (pure css)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Having trouble with how the drop-down-menu looks like when the mouse hovers over it. Note that the problem only started when I converted my nav li's from fixed to fluid. (instead of specifying it in px I specify it in %)

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 99%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 248, 228, 0.95);
  border: 2px solid #585858;
}

a:link {
  color: #e07400;
}

a:visited {
  color: gray;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  font-style: italic;
}

header img {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 136.078px;
}

.orange_header {
  color: #e07400;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 200%;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 1px black;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  padding-left: 7em;
  padding-top: 0.7em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}


/*====================NAV MENU========================*/

#nav_menu a {
  margin: 0;
}

#nav_menu a.current {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  background-color: #a78349;
}

#nav_menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 34px;
}

#nav_menu ul li {
  float: left;
  /*width:165.985px;*/
  /*(800-136.06)/4 - fixed layout - uncomment to see that the dropdown menu at the lessons tab looks fine*/
  width: 20.748125%;
  /* 165.985/800*100 - here the dropdown menu looks strange...how to I fix this?*/
}

#nav_menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ab6b06;
  color: white;
}

#nav_menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

#nav_menu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}

#nav_menu ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block
}

#nav_menu>ul::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <img src="images/guitarlogo2.png" alt="Guitar" height="109.93">
    <h1 class="orange_header">Annemie's Guitar School</h1>
  </header>
  <nav id="nav_menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="useful_links.html">Useful links</a></li>
      <li><a href="lesson_intro.html">Lessons</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="sittingpos.html">Sitting position</a></li>
          <li><a href="readingmusic.html">Reading music</a></li>
          <li><a href="rhtech.html">Right Hand Technique</a></li>
          <li><a href="lhtech.html">Left Hand Technique</a></li>
          <li><a href="pracandmem.html">Practising and Memorization</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this css:

```
#nav_menu ul li {
    float: left;
    /* width: 165.985px; */
    width: 20.748125%;
}
```

to this

```
#nav_menu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    /* width: 165.985px; */
    width: 20.748125%;
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. I want to know why this works though...I am still new to web development

Comment: This sign is one of the `CSS Combinators` you can easily understand what this sign do by checking this link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp